# Boost Thread - How to acknowledge interrupt

Tags: c++, interrupt, boost-thread

I have blocking task which will be performed by find_the_question() function. However, I do not want thread executing this function take more than 10 seconds. So in case it takes more than 10 seconds, I want to close that thread with cleaning all the resources.

I tried to write a code for that, but somehow I am not able to get a interrupt in find_the_question() function if thread takes more than 10 seconds. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
void find_the_question(std::string value)
{
    //allocate x resources
    try{
        //do some process on resources
            sleep(14);
        //clean resources
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& )
    {
        //clean resources
        std::cout << "Worker thread interrupted" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
        boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000);
        std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
        boost::thread t1(find_the_question, "Can you block me");

        t1.interrupt();
        if (t1.timed_join(timeout))
        {
          //finished
          std::cout << "Worker thread finished" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
          //Not finished;
          std::cout << "Worker thread not finished" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "In main end" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:
If t1 takes more than 10 seconds to complete, I am getting following console output.

```
std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Worker thread not finished" << std::endl;
std::cout << "In main end" << std::endl;
```

whereas, I am expecting following output

```
std::cout << "In main" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Worker thread interrupted" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Worker thread not finished" << std::endl;
std::cout << "In main end" << std::endl;
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `sleep(14);` that you are using. Is this a sleep from `boost::thread` or is it the c sleep function? Because interrupt only works on `boost::thread:sleep`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For using boost::thread::interrupt(), you have to use boost::thread::sleep() for it to work.

> A running thread can be interrupted by invoking the interrupt() member
>   function of the corresponding boost::thread object. When the
>   interrupted thread next executes one of the specified interruption
>   points (or if it is currently blocked whilst executing one) with
>   interruption enabled, then a boost::thread_interrupted exception will
>   be thrown in the interrupted thread. If not caught, this will cause
>   the execution of the interrupted thread to terminate. As with any
>   other exception, the stack will be unwound, and destructors for
>   objects of automatic storage duration will be executed

Predefined interruption points:

> The following functions are interruption points, which will throw
>   boost::thread_interrupted if interruption is enabled for the current
>   thread, and interruption is requested for the current thread:

```
boost::thread::join()
boost::thread::timed_join()
boost::condition_variable::wait()
boost::condition_variable::timed_wait()
boost::condition_variable_any::wait()
boost::condition_variable_any::timed_wait()
boost::thread::sleep()
boost::this_thread::sleep()
boost::this_thread::interruption_point()
```