# Boost threads - safe/guaranteed way to handle thread interrupts

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, boost-thread

I am moving a C program using `pthreads` over to C++ and will have to make extensive use of the Boost library for the sake of making the program multi-platform, portable, etc.

When working with a thread in the past, my code will usually have the form:

---

```
void threadFunc(void* pUserData)
{
    if ( !pUserData )
    {
        return;
    }

    myStruct* pData = (myStruct*)pUserData;
    bool bRun;

    lock(pUserData);
    bRun = pUserData->bRun;
    unlock(pUserData);

    while ( bRun )
    {
        // Do some stuff
        // ...
        // ...
        lock(pUserData);
        bRun = pUserData->bRun;
        unlock(pUserData);
    }

    /* Done execution of thread; External thread must have set pUserData->bRun
     * to FALSE.
     */
}
```

---

This works as I would expect. When I want the thread to shut down, I just lock the mutex for the `struct` it's accessing (typically a member of the `struct`), toggle the `bRun` flag, and `join()` on the thread. For boost threads, I've noticed cases with my code where a `timed_join()` times out when doing non-blocking operations, [similar to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316633/boost-thread-how-to-acknowledge-interrupt). This leads me to suspect I'm not using boost threads correctly.

## To the question...

**First,** which of the two general thread structures would be correct for having a thread properly catch the `thread_interrupted` exception?

## Case A

---

```
void threadFunc( void* pUserData )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some stuff
            // ...
            // ...
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& )
        {
            // Thread interrupted; Clean up
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Case B

---

```
void threadFunc( void* pUserData )
{
    try
    {
        while ( 1 )
        {
            // Do some stuff
            // ...
            // ...
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
        }
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& )
    {
        // Thread interrupted; Clean up
    }
}
```

---

**Second,** what would be the appropriate boost function to call in place of sleep if I want the thread to have a **chance** to catch the interrupt call, but not to `sleep()` or give up the remainder of the CPU time slice it currently holds? [From another SO question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103648/boostthis-threadinterruption-point-doesnt-throw-boostthread-interrupted), it seems that the `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()` call might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not 100% sure if it will always work, from what I read in the SO question I referenced it from.

---

**Finally,** it's to my understanding that not calling any manner of boost `sleep()` function or some similar interruption point function in my loop will mean that a `timed_join()` will always timeout, and I'll either have to:

- Forcefully kill the thread.
- Fall back to using a mutex protected flag like in my original C code.

Is this assumption correct?

---

Thank you.

---

## References

1. [Boost Thread - How to acknowledge interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316633/boost-thread-how-to-acknowledge-interrupt), `<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316633/boost-thread-how-to-acknowledge-interrupt>`, Accessed 2016-01-18.
2. [boost::this_thread::interruption_point() doesn't throw boost::thread_interrupted& exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103648/boostthis-threadinterruption-point-doesnt-throw-boostthread-interrupted), `<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103648/boostthis-threadinterruption-point-doesnt-throw-boostthread-interrupted>`, Accessed 2016-01-18.

Comment: What's wrong with the condition variable (which is formalized form of "using a mutex protected flag like in my original C code", with some extra guarantees)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not exception safe. Therefore you're prone to dead lock when you await the join.

If you receive the exception while holding the mutex, your code will never unlock the mutex, likely leading to deadlock in the waiting threads.

Things to check:

1. First and foremost, your code doesn't show, anywhere, how you create the threads that you try to interrupt.

   You *need* to be running it on `boost::thread`-governed thread instances. 
   This should be obvious because it will be hard to call `boost::thread::interrupt()` without such an object. Still, I'd like to double check this is in order, because the function signature for the thread function strongly suggests native POSIX `pthread_create` usage.

   > A good idea is to check the return value of `interrupt_request()` (which [will be `false` for native threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.native_from)):
   >
   > > The `boost::this_thread` interrupt related functions behave in a degraded mode when called from a thread created using the native interface, i.e. `boost::this_thread::interruption_enabled()` returns false. As consequence the use of `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption` and `boost::this_thread::restore_interruption` will do nothing and calls to `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()` will be just ignored.
2. How are the lock/unlock functions implemented? Again the same goes here. If you mix with POSIX/non-boost APIs then you might miss the signal.

   While you're at it, start using `lock_guard` or `unique_lock` so your code is exception safe.
3. Regarding your `Case A` vs `Case B` question, Case B is simplest.

   Case A doesn't show how plan to exit the `while` loop. You could of course use `break`, `return` (or even `goto`) but as you showed it, it will be an infinite loop.
4. Apart from `sleep()` there is `yield()` that expressly gives up the remainder of the timeslice while being an interruption point.

   I know you've said you don't want to give up the timeslice, but I'm not sure you realize this is going cause the thread to burn CPU if there's no work to be done:

   It strikes me as highly contradictory that you wish to *not give up the remainder of the timeslice* (indicating low-latency, high bandwidth applications and a lock-free context) and you're talking about *using `mutex`* at the same time. The latter, obviously, is a lot more expensive than merely `yield`-ing a partial timeslice, as it's the **opposite** of lock-free concurrency.

So let me conclude with two demos of good style, one lockful and one lockless (or lock-conservative, depending on the rest of your thread synchronization logic).

### Lockful Demo

This uses the "old" thread control because it's fine when locking, IMO:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b72a35737c5b709)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void trace(std::string const& msg);

struct myStruct {
    bool keepRunning = true;

    using mutex_t = boost::mutex;
    using lock_t  = boost::unique_lock<mutex_t>;

    lock_t lock() const { return lock_t(mx); }

  private:
    mutex_t mutable mx;
};

void threadFunc(myStruct &userData) {
    trace("threadFunc enter");

    do 
    {
        {
            auto lock = userData.lock();
            if (!userData.keepRunning)
                break;
        } // destructor of unique_lock unlocks, exception safe


        // Do some stuff
        // ...
        // ...
        trace("(work)");
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    } while (true);

    trace("threadFunc exit");
}

int main() {
    trace("Starting main");

    boost::thread_group threads;
    constexpr int N = 4;
    std::vector<myStruct> data(N);

    for (int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(threadFunc, boost::ref(data[i])));

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));

    trace("Main signaling shutdown");

    for (auto& d : data) {
        auto lock = d.lock();
        d.keepRunning = false;
    }

    threads.join_all();
    trace("Bye");
}

void trace(std::string const& msg) {
    static boost::mutex mx;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);

    static int thread_id_gen = 0;
    thread_local int thread_id = thread_id_gen++;

    std::cout << "Thread #" << thread_id << ": " << msg << "\n";
}
```

Output e.g.

```
Thread #0: Starting main
Thread #1: threadFunc enter
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #2: threadFunc enter
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #3: threadFunc enter
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: threadFunc enter
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #4: (work)
Thread #2: (work)
Thread #1: (work)
Thread #3: (work)
Thread #0: Main signaling shutdown
Thread #4: threadFunc exit
Thread #2: threadFunc exit
Thread #1: threadFunc exit
Thread #3: threadFunc exit
Thread #0: Bye
```

### Lockfree Demo

1. A literal translation of the previous lockful example:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca8e1240e8e012c4)</kbd>**
2. However, it might make more sense now to have a single, shared, shutdown flag:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ed93057dbf8e143)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>

   void trace(std::string const& msg);

   struct myStruct {
       int value;
   };

   void threadFunc(myStruct userData, boost::atomic_bool& keepRunning) {
       std::string valuestr = std::to_string(userData.value);
       trace("threadFunc enter(" + valuestr + ")");

       do 
       {
           if (!keepRunning)
               break;

           // Do some stuff
           // ...
           // ...
           trace("(work" + valuestr + ")");
           boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
       } while (true);

       trace("threadFunc " + valuestr + " exit");
   }

   int main() {
       boost::atomic_bool running { true };
       trace("Starting main");

       boost::thread_group threads;
       constexpr int N = 4;

       for (int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
           threads.create_thread(
               boost::bind(threadFunc, myStruct{i}, boost::ref(running)
           ));
       }

       boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));

       trace("Main signaling shutdown");

       running = false;

       threads.join_all();
       trace("Bye");
   }

   void trace(std::string const& msg) {
       static boost::mutex mx;
       boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);

       static int thread_id_gen = 0;
       thread_local int thread_id = thread_id_gen++;

       std::cout << "Thread #" << thread_id << ": " << msg << "\n";
   }
   ```

   Note how it's a lot more "natural C++" the way we can just pass data into the `threadFunc` using `boost::bind`¹
3. With `interruption_point()`

   Note that the docs for `interrupt()` state:

   > Effects: If `*this` refers to a thread of execution, request that the
   >   `thread` will be interrupted the next time it enters one of the
   >   predefined interruption points **with interruption enabled**, or if it is
   >   currently blocked in a call to one of the predefined interruption points
   >   **with interruption enabled** [*emphasis mine*]

   It's worth noting that interruption can be temporarily disabled. Boost only provides RAII-enabled classes for this, so the default would be exception safe. If your code *doesn't* use either [`class disable_interruption` or `class restore_interruption`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.disable_interruption) you don't have to worry about this.

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d29cd08fcddd0687)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>

   void trace(std::string const& msg);

   struct myStruct {
       int value;
   };

   void threadFunc(myStruct userData) {
       std::string valuestr = std::to_string(userData.value);
       trace("threadFunc enter(" + valuestr + ")");

       // using `Case B` form from your question
       try {
           do 
           {
               boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // Avoids huge output for demo

               trace("(work" + valuestr + ")");
               boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
           } while (true);
       } catch(boost::thread_interrupted const& tie) {
           trace("threadFunc " + valuestr + " interrupted");
       }

       trace("threadFunc " + valuestr + " exit");
   }

   int main() {
       trace("Starting main");

       boost::thread_group threads;
       constexpr int N = 4;

       for (int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
           threads.create_thread(boost::bind(threadFunc, myStruct{i}));
       }

       boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));

       trace("Main signaling shutdown");
       threads.interrupt_all();

       threads.join_all();
       trace("Bye");
   }

   void trace(std::string const& msg) {
       static boost::mutex mx;
       boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);

       static int thread_id_gen = 0;
       thread_local int thread_id = thread_id_gen++;

       std::cout << "Thread #" << thread_id << ": " << msg << "\n";
   }
   ```

¹ or lambdas if you preferred

Comment: @Walter Everything stays the same, except for interruption points (which the standard doesn't have). That made it less relevant to the question for now.

Comment: Completed the lockfree/interruption point samples. [Here's the recorded live-stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/thread-shutdown-mutexatomicsinterrupt/) of me answering this question in case you're interested.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful.

Comment: Would using a `scoped_lock()` call be thread safe like your `auto lock...` code? Thanks!

Comment: [`scoped_lock` looks to be a typedef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex). So, no "scoped_lock()" would either be [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) or it would default construct an object of that type (doing nothing). If you meant the type, yeah obviously it's just a typedef for `unique_lock<>` so it's the same.

Comment: (If you meant to say you can't use `auto`, have a look in the `trace` function, it locks a mutex too. [Here's the first sample in C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a589243d52b1217))

Comment: I should correct myself: would using a scoped lock guarantee that it gets unlocked if interrupted like the way you lock (ie: block scope, create automatic mutex, etc)?

Comment: Teaching you to fish: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_guard.lock_guard.destructor